# Parsing filtered rows of pivot table in xlsx with POI

Tags: apache-poi

I'm trying to parse an xlsx file that contains a pivot table with a filter which hides a few rows in the pivot table.  When I parse it, like so (POI v4.1.2):

```
POIXMLTextExtractor extractor = new XSSFExcelExtractor(OPCPackage.open("pivot.xlsx"));
System.out.println(extractor.getText());
```

The filtered rows will not be parsed.  I would like to have all of the data within the table be parsed (filtered rows included) without having to remove the filters on the pivot table.

I know its mentioned in the documentation https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html that

> > XSSF has limited support for creating Pivot Tables, and very limited read/change support.

Is parsing filtered rows of a pivot table not supported?  POI will parse filtered rows on a regular sheet (not in a pivot table) without any issues.

Comment: "POI will parse filtered rows on a regular sheet (not in a pivot table) without any issues." Yes because filtered rows on a regular sheet are only hidden by setting row height 0. But the rows stay there. So the data in that rows can be read. But the sheet representation of a pivot table simply does not contain the filtered data anymore. The data stays only in the data source of the pivot table. So that data source would must be read when all data are needed.

Comment: How exactly do you get access to the datasource?  It is no clear in the api.  A code example would be appreciated.

Comment: That depends on the kind of used data source. And surely this cannot be solved using `XSSFExcelExtractor`. And `XSSFPivotTable` still contains multiple bugs. See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66216, which is one bug while getting `XSSFPivotCacheDefinition` which will contain the data source relation.

Comment: What do you mean by kind of datasource used?  I'm assuming the datasource is cells from a sheet within the same file, would that make any difference?  Also I'm hoping to integrate this with tika if that helps.

Comment: "I'm assuming the data source is cells from a sheet within the same file". That would be one possibility. Others are, data source from a sheet in another workbook, data source from a table in the same workbook respectively in another workbook, data source from an externally data connection, ... You see the complexity?

Comment: Taking your assumption, it would be possible to get the range of the unfiltered raw data, the pivot table uses as data source from the `XSSFPivotCacheDefinition`. But is that what you want? Seems not. Seems as if you want to interact with the pivot table to set all filters off and read the pivoted data. But this is something what Apache POI is far away to support.

Comment: So the only realistic solution at the moment would be to read the raw data from the datasource (data from a sheet within the same file) and programmatically implement the pivot table behavior (minus the filters) during extraction?

Comment: Correct. But not only at the moment. As said, the sheet representation of a pivot table simply does not contain the filtered data anymore. So the **only** solution is using the source data and programmatically implement the pivot table behavior. Either you do this or you wait until `apache poi` provides API methods for this.